# Where to handle exception whether in DAO layer or Delegate layer?

Tags: java, design-patterns

For better designing application:

1. Where to handle exception whether in DAO layer or Delegate layer?
2. Which one is better approach out of 2 given in 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual with "design" questions: It depends.

In general, I would say handle as many exceptions  as possible locally, in this case in the DAO, but you may want to re-throw some exceptions or raise new ones directly.

E.g. if your DAO causes an SQLException, you do not want to let your upper layers even know that SQL is used, so catching this exception early on would be advisable (so you don't have to import SQLException in your Delegate Layer's package). However, re-throwing the SQLException inside a MyCustomDAOException will allow to retain the error information.

tldr; In the DAO, and throw new Exceptions containing the original one if needed.